# While or foreach loops with ifs

Tags: php, mysql

I would like your help because I'm stuck on here:

**SQL:**

```
$testEvents = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE str_to_date(concat(`eventDate`, ' ', `time`), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i')");
$testEvents ->execute();
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
while ( $test = $testEvents->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    if( ! is_numeric($test['eventName'] && is_numeric($test['teamA']) && is_numeric($test['teamB']))) {
        echo $test['eventName'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

#### My target is try to do like:

[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HEqa.png)

Example: If `eventName` **IS NOT** a *number* and `teamA` & `teamB` **ARE NOT NULL** , show `eventName` data.

**AND**

If `teamA` & `teamB` **ARE NOT** a *number* and `eventName` **IS** a number, show `teamA` and `teamB`

**EXPLANATION IN IMAGE:**
[Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQw2B.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apart from your strange database design... to answer your question you can try this...

I made up some test data to simulate your database

```
$data = [
    [
        'eventName'=>'1',
        'teamA'=>'Magallanes',
        'teamB'=>'Caracas',
        'eventDate'=>'17-11-2016',
        'eventTime'=>'11:11'
    ],
    [
        'eventName'=>'Manana',
        'teamA'=>'123',
        'teamB'=>'123',
        'eventDate'=>'17-11-2016',
        'eventTime'=>'12:12'
    ]
];
```

Then tested out the code to perform your loop... You were on the right track but obviously you just gave up....

```
foreach($data as $test) {
    if( ! is_numeric($test['eventName']) && is_numeric($test['teamA']) && is_numeric($test['teamB'])) {
        echo $test['eventName'];
        echo " ";
        echo $test['eventDate'];
        echo " ";
        echo $test['eventTime'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
    else if (is_numeric($test['eventName']) && ! is_numeric($test['teamA']) && ! is_numeric($test['teamB'])) {
        echo $test['teamA'];
        echo " x ";
        echo $test['teamB'];
        echo "  ";
        echo $test['eventDate'];
        echo " ";
        echo $test['eventTime'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

**The Results**

```
Magallanes x Caracas 17-11-2016 11:11
Manana 17-11-2016 12:12
```

Swap and change things as you require.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    while ( $test = $testEvents->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
    {    
       if( ! is_numeric($test['eventName']) && is_numeric($test['teamA']) && is_numeric($test['teamB'])) 
       {
          echo $test['eventName']." ".$test['eventDate']." ".$test['eventTime']."<br>";
       }
       else if (is_numeric($test['eventName']) && ! is_numeric($test['teamA']) && ! is_numeric($test['teamB'])) 
       {
          echo $test['teamA']." x ".$test['teamB']."  ".$test['eventDate']." ".$test['eventTime']."<br>";
       }
    }
?>
```